# Content alignment within a bootstrap column?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am a bit new to bootstrap and would like some guidance regarding how to use "d-flex" to align the content center. I tried applying "d-flex justify-content-center" like what the documentation says but the alignments still does not work. Is there anything I am doing wrong? I attached an image below; looking for centered spacing after the "Testing!" so the pictures are more aligned in the center from top to bottom. I believe I got the horizontal alignment correct.

````
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col text-center">
                <h1>Testing!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row body text-center">
            <div class="col-6">
                <h2>Shop Collections</h2>
                <img class="img-fluid"src="images/rx782alloy.jpg" >
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <h2>Catalog</h2>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="images/batmanbeyond.jpg" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz54x.png
````

Comment: Anytime you have a HTML, CSS, and/or Javascript question, a jsfiddle is a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this fiddle. I believe this will answer your question. I have given you a guideline that will clarify your concept regarding d-flex. The design is responsive, change the view to see the result.

https://jsfiddle.net/hilalrehan/9vyd6Lu2/140/

```css
.adjust {
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.text-area{
  min-height: 139px;
}

.box {
    padding: 0.2rem;
    flex: 0 0 20rem;
  
    }
    
.set{
    flex-flow: wrap;
justify-content: center;
min-width: 20rem;
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 576px) { 
  .set {
    max-width: none;
}

.box {
    padding: 0rem;
}
  }
  
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .set {
    justify-content: flex-end;
  
}

.box {
    flex: 0 0 8rem;
}
  
}
```

```html
<html>
 <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 order-2 order-lg-6 col-xl-6">
        <h2 class="display-2"> Testing </h2>
                    <div class="d-flex set mx-auto  ">
                     <div class="box">
                            <div class="text-area display-4 text-center  text-white bg-success"> Shop Collections </div>
                    <div class="img bg-success"> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz54x.png" class="img-fluid"> </div>
                </div>
                   <div class="box">
                           <div class="text-area display-4 text-center adjust-text black bg-warning"> <div class="adjust"> Catalog</div> </div>
                   <div class="img bg-white "> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz54x.png" class="img-fluid" > </div>

                </div>
                </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```